# Electron ipcRenderer invoke doesn't work when second-instance is called

Tags: javascript, electron, invoke, ipcrenderer

In Electron, ipcRenderer.invoke() Does not work after app is opened while an instance is already created. Here is my code:

```
// Force Single Instance Application
const gotTheLock = app.requestSingleInstanceLock()
if (gotTheLock) {
  app.on('second-instance', (e, argv) => {
    // Someone tried to run a second instance, we should focus our window.

// Protocol handler for win32
// argv: An array of the second instance’s (command line / deep linked) arguments
if (process.platform == 'win32') {
  // Keep only command line / deep linked arguments
  deeplinkingUrl = argv.slice(1);
}
if (deeplinkingUrl.length > 0) {
  mainWindow.webContents.send('url', deeplinkingUrl);
}
logEverywhere('app.makeSingleInstance# ' + deeplinkingUrl);

if (mainWindow) {
  if (mainWindow.isMinimized()) {
    mainWindow.restore();
  }
  mainWindow.focus();
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  mainWindow = createWindow()
})
  })
} else {
  app.quit();
}
```

Is there another way of sending information from the renderer to the main without using ipcRenderer.invoke() and ipcMain.handle()? Or is there a way to continue using ipcRenderer.invoke()?

An example of my renderer code that works on the first instance but not on the second

```
while (
        (await ipcRenderer.invoke(
          "getVariableValue",
          "storageEncrypted"
        )) == false
      ) {
```

Comment: post your renderer code

Comment: I posted an example of my renderer code that doesn't work on the second instance.